# Flutter: getting css :after kind of effect for image to apply background

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have CSS rule to add background to the images have a white background as follows

```
.product-img:after {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: rgba(40,44,63,.05);
   content: '';
   background-blend-mode: overlay;
 }
```

Results [![enter image description here][3]][3]

want to get the same effect in a flutter, I have tried a couple of widgets like Stack, Position,
but couldn't achieve the same effect.

My Image loading widget:

```
FadeInImage(
   image: NetworkImage(
   "my-url"
   ),
   placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/load_fut.png'),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your images have solid white background. So to display on top of white background need to play bit with blendmode to achieve desired effect. Here is output close to what you're trying to achieve.

Update : Using `cached_network_image`

Add Depednecy
`cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1`

```
  @override
  _ColorPageState createState() => _ColorPageState();
}

class _ColorPageState extends State<ColorPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    CachedNetworkImage(
      height: 200,
      width: 400,
      colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
      color: Color.fromARGB(20, 40, 44, 63),
      imageUrl:
          "https://tacskey.com/image/cache/catalog/categories/Cold%20Cuts/chicken-nuggets-600x350.jpg",
      placeholder: (context, url) =>  Image.asset(
          'assets/loader_.png',
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
      ),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    );
  }
}
```

Output gif :

[image]

Comment: How do i combine with FadeInImage() widget, Please see my updated question

Comment: It is not possible with FadeInImage. CachedImage is better alternative for it. I'll update answer with it.

Comment: @maaz Check updated answer. Please Accept if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If by "images [that] have a white background, " you mean transparent images, then to give images of that type a background color, you can wrap the `Image` widget with a `Container` widget and give it your desired color and that will be the background color.

Like below:

```
Container(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 44, 100, .05),
    child: Image.network(imageUrl)
)
```